# Удаление хеша из url (/#/) средствами сервера

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

Добрый день, профессионалы. У меня возникла неразрешимая задача - необходимо вырезать хеш из url. Например, из этого:

```
http://site.com/#/page
```

в это:

```
http://site.com/page
```

Также, необходимо учитывать, что на сайте существуют категории:

```
http://site.com/category/#/catname
```

Пытаюсь решить своими силами (копаюсь в документации apache), но процесс не идет, так как этим я до этого вообще не занимался (до администрирования руки не доходили - только фронтенд).

Помогите создать правило для htaccess.

Comment: Я использую History API, а для древних браузеров использую полифилл который вставляет хеши. Проблема не масштабная, но имеет место быть - пользователи старых браузеров публикуют ссылку на контент с хешем, а пользователи браузеров с выключенным js переходят по ней. Ясен пень, что шансы на повторение ситуации снижаются на каждом из этих этапов, но мне нужен каждый пользователь и остутствие ошибок. Ошибка возникает тогда, когда пользователь с откл js переходит по ссылке с хешем и натыкается на ошибку/редирект на главную (как в wordpress), а не целевой материал за которым пришел

Comment: Накопал:

Redirecting Anchors
Description:
By default, redirecting to an HTML anchor doesn't work, because mod_rewrite escapes the# character, turning it into%23. This, in turn, breaks the redirection.
Solution:
Use the[NE] flag on theRewriteRule. NE stands for No Escape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задача и вправду неразрешимая, т.к. хэш не посылается серверу, не верите воспользуйтесь wireshark.

Comment: Если это так, до придертся искать хитровыкрученные костыли, но уже на php. Вообще я бы мог сделать это на javascript, но именно люди без включенного js и некоторые отдельные поисковики мешают мне сделать это.

Comment: а php вам чем поможет ? я же говорю, часть после # вообще не передается на сервер. поисковики никогда не пришлют вам url c # :) я как понимаю у вас там ajax который должен без js работать, так вы наоборот, меняйте на хэш ссылки с пом-ю js (оно вообще надо, только там где history api не поддерживается), а генерируйте нормальные страницы.

Comment: Вы оказались правы, но остался шанс, надеюсь..:

Redirecting Anchors
Description:
By default, redirecting to an HTML anchor doesn't work, because mod_rewrite escapes the# character, turning it into%23. This, in turn, breaks the redirection.
Solution:
Use the[NE] flag on theRewriteRule. NE stands for No Escape.

Comment: это **to** html anchor, а не from :)